# Data Type Mismatch Gridview UPDATE

Tags: asp.net, gridview

cannot figure out what the data mismatch is referring too, AutoNum is Int32 and UID is String or Int32, neither works?

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
    BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" 
    DataKeyNames="AutoNum" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" 
    AutoGenerateEditButton="true" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true">
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#6699CC" />
</asp:GridView>

<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AccessSubSiteString %>"
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [UsersDataCareerTbl] WHERE [AutoNum] = ?" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM UsersDataCareerTbl"
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [UsersDataCareerTbl] SET UID = ?  WHERE [AutoNum] = ?">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="AutoNum" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="UID" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="AutoNum" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:AccessDataSource>
```

error message is:
 Data type mismatch in criteria expression.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

Comment: If you try to delete a row did you get the same error message?

Comment: no - delete works fine

Comment: So the type mismatch should be caused by the datatype of the UID. What is the datatype of this column in the database?

Comment: its an Access DB : Integer

Comment: But you define the UpdateParameter as a string.... this is a possible cause of the type mismatch (db expects an integer but receives a string)

Comment: correction: in the DB its "Number" - and I have tried Int32 as the Type - still fails

Comment: Number it is just an oversimplification of Access. If you look at the properties you could see the details of the Number field. Long Integer, Single precision, double precision. It is important because it translates to a different NET datatype

Comment: its "Long Integer" with Auto for Decimal Places

Comment: Long Integer is Int32 (no decimals), so we are back at the starting point. The parameter should be of type Int32. This is certain.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57183/discussion-between-steve-and-barclayvision).